# Joomla Cron for administration

Tags: joomla, cron

In my website, I want to update data from external source everyday.
I create an administration module and he works manually but I need automate the process.
I think a cron can do that but the problem is the login ?

Joomla 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the cronjob on the joomla server needs no login. Login is only needed via Http Requests, A cron job on the server dosent need a login (cron job on same server with joomla)

But as module it will not work. Why just hit a php script as cronjob?
A module needs joomla rendering in most cases and this will not work!

Comment: You can write a joomla CLI application and then you have to tell the server to run it as a cron job in the regular way that you do that on your server.  You could write a way to manage that from the Joomla UI, if that makes sense for some reason.

Comment: Month later but thank you, perfect answer. I put my modules in /cli and call a cron from there. Perfect !